# spring-authorization-server : Override redirect_uri validator

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I am replacing an existing application that currently uses the now deprecated `spring-security-oauth2` with the new `spring-authorization-server`

At [OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationValidator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationValidator.java#L117), there is logic implement to perform exact-matching of the redirect uri as per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-22#section-4.1.3 :

```
private static void validateRedirectUri(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext authenticationContext) {
...
            if (!isLoopbackAddress(requestedRedirect.getHost())) {
                // As per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-22#section-4.1.3
                // When comparing client redirect URIs against pre-registered URIs,
                // authorization servers MUST utilize exact string matching.
                if (!registeredClient.getRedirectUris().contains(requestedRedirectUri)) {
                    throwError(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST, OAuth2ParameterNames.REDIRECT_URI,
                            authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication, registeredClient);
                }
            }
```

Problem is, the current clients always send a redirect URI that contain query parameters, where the query parameters are variable.

So I need to override the redirect uri validation to perform "starts with matching" instead of "exact matching", but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions on how to go about it ?

Yes, I understand this is against the guidance. These are all internal-only applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the spec, these supposed to be query parameters should be stored in the state parameter instead.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.2

> The authorization server SHOULD require the client to provide the
> complete redirection URI (the client MAY use the "state" request
> parameter to achieve per-request customization).

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to do this under [Customizing Authorization Request Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-authorization-endpoint-customizing-authorization-request-validation) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks .. although I realised that query parameters on the redirect URI should never be be done and such customization should really be part of the state parameter.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd have to check again, but I'm surprised query parameters were a problem for you. I would expect that you can actually pass additional query params without issues.